# Projection of containers, i.e. method to transform List<Object> to List<Object.Member>

Tags: java, list, java-stream, collectors

I have a List of Objects, lets say `List<Example>` and the class Example has a member a which is a String:

```
class Example {
    String a;
    String b;
}
```

Now I would like to get from `List<Example>` to `List<String>` by using only the **a** elements from each member of the list.

Of course this is easy to do with a loop, but I was trying to find something similar to the algorithms in C++ which could do this directly.

**Question**: What is the simplest way to project from List to List, in which the values are the field `a` of `Example`?

---

Edit: this is what I meant by for loop:

```
List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
for(Example e : myList)
    result.add(e.a);
return result;
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a simple solution using Java 8's declarative stream mapping:

```
class Example {
    String a;
    String b;
    // methods below for testing
    public Example(String a) {
        this.a = a;
    }
    public String getA() {
        return a;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("Example with a = %s", a);
    }
}
// initializing test list of Examples
List<Example> list = Arrays.asList(new Example("a"), new Example("b"));

// printing original list
System.out.println(list);

// initializing projected list by mapping
// this is where the real work is

List<String> newList = list
    // streaming list
    .stream()
    // mapping to String through method reference
    .map(Example::getA)
    // collecting to list
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

// printing projected list
System.out.println(newList);
```

**Output**

```
[Example with a = a, Example with a = b]
[a, b]
```

**Docs**

- General package API on Java 8 streams [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html)
- Specific API on `Stream#map` method [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-)

Comment: Wow. This is really neat XD

Comment: @ItamarGreen glad you like it :) And yes, Java 8's functional-style programming features are sweet!

Comment: The funny thing is, you could use the same technique of the solution to build the test data: `List<Example> list=Stream.of("a","b").map(Example::new).collect(Collectors.toList());`

Comment: @Holger good one. Although a little more verbose than the current one in my opinion.

Comment: Try it with twenty or forty example objects… ;^)

Comment: @Holger true, in another context your idiom would be much better.

Answer (score 2):

You can use streams in java8

```
List<Example> l = Arrays.asList(new Example("a", "a"), new Example("b", "b"), new Example("c", "c"),
               new Example("d", "d"));
List<String> names = l.stream().map(Example::getA).collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(names);
```